# A telescoping sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The problem goes as follows

Define a sqeuence $ \{ x_n \}_{n >=1 }$ by $ x_1=\frac{1}{2} $ and $ x_{n+1}= {x_n}^2 +x_n $ . Find the greatest integer  less than

$\sum_{r=1}^{2019}$ $\frac {1}{x_r +1}$.

$\mathbf {My}$ $\mathbf {Try}$ :-

given $ x_{n+1}= {x_n}^2 +x_n $, we can factor $x_n$ from the RHS and we get

$\frac {x_n} {x_{n+1} } $ =$ \frac {1}{x_n +1} $

However, this does not simplify the problem any further.

Next, I tried to make the RHS look a bit better by making a perfect square

$x_{n+1}= ( x_n +\frac{1}{2} )^2 -\frac{1}{4} $

This also didn't make any progress and I am now stuck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thank you very much! I don't know why but it didn't come up in my search results

Comment: Duplicate target found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Br%3D1%7D%5E%7B2019%7D%5Cfrac%20%7B1%7D%7Bx_r%20%2B1%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%20%7Bx_n%7D%5E2%20%2Bx_n%24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{x_{n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{x_n^2 + x_n} = \dfrac{1}{x_n} - \dfrac{1}{x_n+1}\implies \dfrac{1}{x_n+1} = \dfrac{1}{x_n} - \dfrac{1}{x_{n+1}}$. Can you take it from here using telescoping technique?

Comment: Thank you very much! i totally missed that :p

Comment: @AnujJha: You are welcome.